# Serving dynamic URLs with express and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, url, express

I'm building a site that has somewhat reddit-like functionality. I want user-submitted content to get its own page. Each submission is assigned a 5 character ID that I want to be in the URL for that page.

I've got this function in the router file which renders a page called titles:

```
exports.titles = function(req, res){
i = 0
read(function(post){
    url = post[i].URL;
    res.render('titles', {title: post[i].title, url: post[i].URL});
});

};
```

It is served by this statement in app.js:

```
app.get('/titles', home.titles); //home.js is the router file
```

The titles page has a link with the text post.title and the URL post.URL. When a user clicks on the link (e.g. domain.com/12345) they should be taken to a page called content with the content post.body.

How do I a)pass the URL back to my app.js file to include in an app.get, b) include the app.get function in this router file, or c) solve this in any other way?

Edit: I do have an object 'titles' that is a mongodb collection, but it is in a different module. No reason I can't add it to the router though.

Edit: I tried adding this to app.js to see if it would work:

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res){
  return titles.findOne({ id: req.params.id }, function (err, post) {
    if (err) throw(err); 

    return res.render('content', {title: post.title, content: post.body});
   });
});
```

Edit: I got it to work. All I did was format the title so that it would look like domain.com/titles/12345 and change app.get('/:id', to app.get('/titles/:id, ...

Comment: what is the 'content' ? Is that one of your views ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I get you right I would do that the other way around.

### Short version

1. I would get the `id` from the URL
2. Then I would pull from the database the data associated with this `id`
3. And use this data to build the final page.

You don't need to create a new route for each URL. An URL can contain some variable (here the `id`) and Express can parse the URL in order to get this variable. Then from this `id` you can get the data needed to build the proper page.

### Long version

I assuming someone type in this URL: `http://domain.com/1234`.
I also assume that you have a variable `titles` which is a MongoDB Collection.

You can have a route defined like this:

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  // Then you can use the value of the id with req.params.id
  // So you use it to get the data from your database:
  return titles.findOne({ id: req.params.id }, function (err, post) {
    if (err) { throw(err); }

    return res.render('titles', {title: post.title, url: post.URL /*, other data you need... */});
  });
});
```

#### Edit

I made some changes according to the last comments...

Comment: Uh, I'm pretty sure I don't have a post model. What exactly is that? It sounds useful.

Comment: A model is just an 'object' which helps you pull/push data to the database. That's an abstraction layer and it can really help you. Maybe you can add some code on how you get data from the database?

Comment: I have this function in another module:
`exports.read = function(callback){

 titles.find().toArray(function(err, result){
  if (err) throw err;
  callback(result);

 });
};`

Which passes the retrieved object to this function in the router file:
`read = function(callback){
  postdb.read(function(post){
   callback(post);
  });
 };`
Right now I have it set up to parse the array by entry number, but I'm going to change it to use the ID.

Comment: I found this site: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/post.model

Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: I edited the answer. Maybe it'll be closer to what you're looking for. But if you could edit your question and add more code and the file architecture... =)

Comment: Forget the model. It's not important right now. Your `titles` variable should do the job. (I meant something like [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) )

Comment: I added some more info. Your edits were helpful, but I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work using that function. I edited my question with my solution. Thanks!