# How do I create a link that is unique to a users data?

Tags: node.js, firebase

Im trying to store the information the user enters in a field to a JSON file and then giving it a new link where the page is the exact copy of the first one, but the user data is already put in. This link should be automatically generated when the user hits save data.

Comment: can you provide something you tried?

Comment: Im still in the idea phase but, this is exactly what I want to do [link](https://optioncreator.com/),  when you hit save it generates a new page with the data I have entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the limited information that you've given me, this is what I would recommend that you look into.
What you want to do, is essentially create a URL that can serve the user's information on a [GET](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/listtutorial/Difference-between-GET-and-POST-method-in-HTTP/3916) request. There are a few ways to get started on this, but one I would recommend looking into is via what's referred to as a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Another way to handle this is [dynamic routing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_url_building.htm). This is how I would typically see something like this working out:

1. A user creates some data about themselves, which you save (I'd recommend a database instead of a plain JSON file, [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) may be a good starting point if you want to stick close to JSON)
2. On the user entering some information, you create some form of identification for that entry - this could be a hashed version of the user's email ID, or just an integer ID that is linked to that entry. Thus, instead of your JSON being `{ data: data }`, it would look something like `{ id: x, data: data }`
3. Once this is done, you can have another page that expects a URL like `/getUserData/?id=x` (query string) OR `/getData/id` (dynamic route) - you can then use [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), or whatever server-side framework you're using to extract the id parameter, fetch the data using the parameter you just extracted, and use that to return the data the user needs.

EDIT: The [Options Strategy Builder](https://optioncreator.com) you've linked in your comment does something very similar - they just generate a unique ID per setup, and use that ID to route to that session. This is probably built using [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), and you can see how to do something like that in React [here](https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-url-parameters). If you want to do this using ExpressJS, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747740/serving-dynamic-urls-with-express-and-mongodb) out.

Comment: Thank you for  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747740/serving-dynamic-urls-with-express-and-mongodb) this is what I intended to do